# How do I add a attribute to a ng-template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a search component with a ng-template derived from a directive `TableHeaderDirective`

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appTableHeader]'
})
export class TableHeaderDirective {
    @Input() filter = 'click'; // pass desired event
    constructor(public tpl: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

I have this working and the template setup. Now I want to add the filter Attribute like below:

```html
<sym-search [search]="searchString" [data]="data">
    <ng-template appTableHeadersTemplate>
        <ng-template appTableHeader [filter]="'Username'">
            Username
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template appTableHeader filter="'FirstName'">
            First Name
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template appTableHeader filter="'LastName'">
            Last Name
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
</sym-search>
```

I later want this in the search component by getting the children for the templates

```js
@ContentChildren(TableHeaderDirective, { read: TemplateRef })
tableHeaderItems: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

and then looping to output th tags

```html
<th *ngFor="let headerItem of tableHeaderItems; index as i;">
{{headerItem.filter}}
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerItem"></ng-container>
</th>
```

**How can I get access to the [Filter] so that I can added it to the th tag?**

Do I need to create a filterDirective and if so how do I access it on the search component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading template reference you can read directive reference. so that you can access directive template reference and input property inside your component.

**Try this**

**component.ts**

```
@ContentChildren(TableHeaderDirective, { read: TableHeaderDirective }) tableHeaderItems: QueryList<TableHeaderDirective<any>>;
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmazse)

**component.html**

```
<th *ngFor="let headerItem of tableHeaderItems; index as i;">
   {{headerItem.filter}}
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerItem.tpl"></ng-container>
</th>
```