# how to access templateRef attributes

Tags: angular

considering the following template snippet

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
<button mat-list-item *ngFor="let t of templates" (click)="template = t.template">
    {{ ..........}}
</button>

<ng-template #tUser label="User 1">
        user
</ng-template>

<ng-template #tUser label="User 2">
        user2
</ng-template>

<ng-template #tUser label="User 3">
        user3
</ng-template>
```

how can I access the `label` attribute inside the `ngFor` ?

edit:

```
  @ViewChildren('tUser') templates!: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

edit 2: Even if it looks nice this seams to be a rabbit whole. I my project this works because I use Firebase and I have a lot of `detectChanges()` fired from a lot of places. When used in a clean project you need to manually trigger `detectChanges()` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>` and  `(click)="template = t.template"` will do the rendering. The code works I only need a method to access the label. It would be great if it would work without adding code inside component.ts

Comment: Could you at least provide the value for the "templates" array and how do you populate it?

Comment: What is in the template array ?

Comment: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;

Comment: I don't think this is doable in the way you want to implement it: If you iterate over the QueryList elements you get the TemplateRef. And only property you can access in the ngFor is the "elementRef" and "nativeElement". But since the ng-template is rendered as a comment html-element, there is no attributes you can access.

Comment: I think this question could help you with the implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771664/how-do-i-add-a-attribute-to-a-ng-template

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the usage of `ng-template` means transformation into comment in the HTML DOM model. So you have no access to any custom attributes here. But you can go another way and use `directive`. Put the directive on each template, provide the value and get this values list.

Here how you code can look like:

`my-label.directive.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myLabel]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyLabelDirective {
  @Input()
  myLabel?: string;

  readonly template = inject(TemplateRef);
}
```

`your-template.html`

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
<button mat-list-item *ngFor="let t of templates" (click)="template = t.template">
    {{ ..........}}
</button>

<ng-template #tUser myLabel="User 1">
        user
</ng-template>

<ng-template #tUser myLabel ="User 2">
        user2
</ng-template>

<ng-template #tUser myLabel ="User 3">
        user3
</ng-template>
```

`your-class.ts`

```
...
@ViewChildren(MyLabelDirective) templates!: QueryList<MyLabelDirective>;
...
```

Hence this you can get access to your labels by `myLabel` property in the directive;

Comment: For some reason `templates` is empty

Comment: Have you imported `MyLabelDirective` into your component/module?

Comment: yes, I understood how it should work but ViewChildren will not grab the references

Comment: Here working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ftels6?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: same code in angular 14 does not work :(

Comment: it works, you have a mistake somewhere